# List being emptied on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a C# application where I need the list to "remember" what has been previously entered in it.

http://oi40.tinypic.com/2ivhcuw.jpg

So once the attendee has been added, the previous attendee will stay in the list if a new one is added. Currently it just displays the most recent attendee, I want them to save, until I decide to clear them (maybe in a session?)

```
List<Information> infoList = new List<Information>();
Information data = new Information();

firstName = resultEntry.Properties["givenname"].Value.ToString();
lastName = resultEntry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

//data.CWID = resultEntry.Properties["username"].Value.ToString();
data.FullName = fullName;
// data.Email = resultEntry.Properties["email"].Value.ToString();

infoList.Add(data);
```

Comment: When working in asp.net, there are several ways for 'remembering' a property, you could place it in a session or a hiddenfield. or you could remember it in a database and delete it afterwards if it wasn't used

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing items into a session:

```
Session["MyInformation"] = data;
```

receiving data out of a session

```
List<information> data = (List<information>)Session["MyInformation"];
```

But beware: Sessions ought to be forgotten.

One might consider viewstate but beware here to: viewstates do make a page slow. (easy testings in how big a html page gets when viewstate is added)

one last option might be to include cookies for getting a longer hold on the items.

Write a cookie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd(v=vs.100).aspx

Read a cookie : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18(v=vs.100).aspx

another option is to hold the data in database => this however means more traffic.

(also a small hint on the sessions, place them in a seperate static class so you can get them through the whole project instead of one page

```
public static class MySessions
{
    public static List<Information> MyData
    {
     get{
        //EDIT in the GET
        if(HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInformation"] != null)
          return (List<information>)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInformation"];
        else
          {
          HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInformation"] = new List<Information>();
          return new List<Information>();
          } 
         }
     set{HttpContext.Current.Session["MyInformation"] = value;}
    }
}
```

EDIT:

use the class as follows: (it's a static class, by entering the classname followed by the property, you can call for it instead of first instantiating the class.

```
//Set the value from Somewhere
MySessions.MyData = new List<Information>();

//get the values from somewhere
var myInfo = MySessions.MyData;
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I've put the class in as you suggested but it returns an error "The name session does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Corbin Spider: change Session to HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: @Scheure thanks that cleared the error - now how do I use the class to store/retrieve data to the list (sorry I'm new at this!)

Comment: edited the answer: also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx for use of static classes

Comment: Where do I use:   var myInfo = MySessions.MyData;

I don't seem to be pulling the data which is stored? It still only shows one attendee @Schuere

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the length of the duration of "saving":

Use `ViewState` - if you want the list to be empty on a page load (not postback). (i.e. `ViewState["data"] = infoList`)

Use `Session` - if you want to manually empty the list based on some condition.

Comment: thanks, @Candide So how would this apply to my code? Where do I initialize the session and where to I pull the data in from the session?

Comment: Good answer but you should be aware that if your list is quite large, using the Viewstate will clutter the page loadings.

Comment: @Ethenyl Yes true, however, it is highly unlikely that a user will enter thousands of entries.

Comment: @Candide True, but it should be somewhere in his mind if slugginesh happens ^^

Comment: +1 for Ethenyl, Remember, a page consists out of more then only 1 list